# Making UI Changes on CTCallStateDisconnected

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, core-telephony

When using CoreTelephony, how can I make a UI change once the application returns from the phone call?

I have the following:

```
@IBAction func callNumber(sender: CallButton) {
    callCenter?.callEventHandler = { (call: CTCall) -> () in
        if call.callState == "CTCallStateDisconnected" {
            self.presentModalView
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.handleModalStyling()
            })
        }
    }

    sender.callContact()
}

private func handleModalStyling() {
    self.view.layer.opacity = 0.4
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.opacity = 0.4
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.enabled = false
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = false
}
```

The modal view definitely displays as intended, but the associated opacity changes don't occur. Note that `handleModalStyling` is being called within `presentModalView`.

EDIT:

I've found the solution.In case anyone runs into this in the future, `CTCallCenter.callEventHandler` operates on a high priority thread, *not* the main thread. This means that the `handleStyling` call within the `displayModalView` method was not being called on the correct thread, and this lead to a failure to display the changes.